# Paramiko check login timeout of SSH Server

Tags: python, paramiko

I want to see how long it takes my ssh server to close the connection if the user does not login.

What i have so far

```
self.sshobj = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.sshobj.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
self.sshobj.connect("192.168.0.1", port=22, username="test", password="test")
self.channel = self.sshobj.invoke_shell()
```

But the problem is that i don't want to login , which sshobj.connect does,  i want to be in the login screen.

[image: Login Screen]

And i want to check how long it takes for the server to close the connection.

[image]

Is there any way to do this via paramiko ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not necessarily need paramiko to check the `LoginGraceTime` but since you're specifically asking for it:

*Note:* `banner_timeout` is just a timeout for the peer ssh banner response.
*Note:* `timeout` is actually a socket read timeout, `none` is no timeout. Use this to set a hard-timeout for your check.

```
self.sshobj = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.sshobj.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    self.sshobj.connect("192.168.0.1", port=22, look_for_keys=False, timeout=None, banner_timeout=5)
except paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException, se:
    # paramiko raises SSHException('No authentication methods available',) since we did not specify any auth methods. socket stays open.
    pass
ts_start = time.time()
try:
    self.channel = self.sshobj.invoke_shell()
except EOFError, e:
    # EOFError is raised when peer terminates session.
    pass
print time.time()-ts_start
```

You can even get rid of the first `try_catch` for `No authentication methods available` by overriding `self.sshobj._auth` with an `NOP`. Below are some changes to the first variant:

```
def noauth(username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent,
       look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host): pass
...
sshobj._auth = noauth
sshobj.connect("192.168.0.1", port=22, look_for_keys=False, timeout=None, banner_timeout=5)
...
```

But, as initially mentioned, you do not even need paramiko to test this timeout since the `LoginGraceTime` triggers like a server-side socket read timeout once banners are exchanged. Therefore you just need to establish a TCP connection, send a fake ssh banner and wait until the remote side disconnects:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.0.1", 22))
s.sendall("SSH-2.0-MyPythonSSHProbingClient")
s.settimeout(5*60)  # hard-limit
print s.recv(500)   # remote banner
ts_start = time.time()
if not s.recv(100):
    # exits when remote site closes connection, or raises socket.timeout when hard-limit is hit.
    print time.time()-ts_start
else:
    raise Exception("whoop, something's gone wrong")
```

The non-paramiko variant is even more accurate.